Import "tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping ModelCheckpoint" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Problem Statement: I was trying to import Keras components like ModelCheckpoint and EarlyStopping in my TensorFlow project using the following import statements:
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping ModelCheckpoint

or
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping ModelCheckpoint

However, I kept getting the error: Import "keras.callbacks" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImport.
Even though I had successfully installed TensorFlow and Keras, the error persisted, and no solution seemed to work at first.
Solution: It turns out that Keras is now using a slightly different structure when you're working directly with the library. Instead of importing directly from keras, I had to modify the imports to point to the keras.src subdirectory.
Here’s what worked for me:
from keras.src.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.src.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

Once I switched to using the keras.src path, the imports worked perfectly, and Pylance no longer showed the missing import error.

I'm using TensorFlow 2.17.0 and Keras 3.5.0 installed via pip install tensorflow.

My IDE is Visual Studio Code, and the issue seemed to be specific to Pylance.



Please do not include the answer in the question; post it as a proper answer.
